# Derivation of the given formula for the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

> Given $g:[0,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(0)=0,$ derive the formula
>   $$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{4 (t-s)}} g(s)~ds,~~x > 0$$
>   for a solution of the IVP/BVP
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> u_t - u_{xx}=0~~&\text{in}~~\mathbb{R}_{+} \times (0,\infty) \\
> u=0~~&\text{on}~~\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \{ t=0  \}, \\ 
> u=g~~&\text{on}~~\{ x=0 \} \times [0,\infty).
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   (Hint. Let $v(x,t):=u(x,t)-g(t)$ and extend $v$ to $\{ x< 0 \}$ by odd reflection.)

**My approach**: As suggested in the Hint, define
$$
v(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
u(x,t)- g(t)~~& x >0, \\
-u(-x,t)- g(t)~~& x \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
So we have
$$
v_t(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
u_t(x,t)- g'(t)~~& x >0, \\
-u_t(-x,t)- g'(t)~~& x \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
v_{xx}(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
u_{xx}(x,t)- g(t)~~& x >0, \\
-u_{xx}(-x,t)- g(t)~~& x \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $v$ satisfies the IVP/BVP
$$
\begin{cases}
& v_t(x,t)-v_{xx}(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
-g'(t)~~& x >0, \\
g'(t)~~& x \leq 0.
\end{cases} \\
&v(x,0)=0, \\
&v(0,t)=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Using the solution formula for $v,$ we get
\begin{align*}
v(x,t)&=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi (t-s)}} \bigg\{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(y-x)^2}{4 (t-s)}} g'(x)~dy  \bigg\}~ds \\
&=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi (t-s)}} \bigg\{ \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{\frac{-(y-x)^2}{4 (t-s)}} g'(x)~dy - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(y-x)^2}{4 (t-s)}} g'(s)~dy  \bigg\}~ds.
\end{align*}

I'm stuck here. Any help in continuing from here onwards to obtain the desired result is much appreciated.

Comment: I think by odd reflection, it might mean to let $ v(x,t) = - ( u(-x,t) - g(t) ) $ for $ x < 0 $.

Comment: There are some mistakes here - sign of $g$, derivation of $v_{xx}$, argument of $g$ in the integrals.

Comment: That's the hint and the result of the odd reflection.

Comment: something is off here. The proposed solution satisfies $u(0,t) = 0$ and not $u(0,t) = g(t)$.

Comment: This exercise is From Evan's (page 88, Problem no. 13).